# EF5 How to get the schema and table name from a dbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to write an extension that should get the table name and the schema from a dbSet.

```
public static string GetTableInfo<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
{
    var tableName = ?? // how to retrieve if from the dbSet ? 
    var schemaName = ?? // how to retrieve if from the dbSet ? 

    return $"{schemaName}.{tableName}";
}
```

**Usage :**

```
var tableInfo = _libraryContext.Books.GetTableInfo();
// tableInfo should return "dbo.Book"
```

how i can get the table and schema names directly from the DbSet ?

Comment: You can't do it with a `DbSet`. You'll need to use ADO.NET directly: i.e. `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable`, etc.

Comment: @Dai, i already call a DbContext => _libraryContext.Books.GetTableInfo() so i cannot really use ADO.Net directly

Answer (score 0):

See if you can take the following and adapt to your code as this is close but  not exactly what you wanted.

In the dbContext

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
```

Extension method

```
public static class EntityHelpers
{
    public static string GetTableNameWithScheme<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class
    {
        var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
        var schema = entityType.GetDefaultSchema();
        return $"{schema ?? "(unknown)"}.{entityType.GetTableName()}";
    }
}
```

Example

```
using var context = new YourContext();
Console.WriteLine(context.GetTableNameWithScheme<YourModel>());
```